# JSF bean property not evaluated in external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jsf, jakarta-ee, el

If I want to evaluate a JSF bean property from within JavaScript, I see that it works if the JavaScript snippet is inside the xhtml file, but doesn't work when the JavaScript snippet is in a separate js file.

So, this works:

**index.xhtml**

```
...
<h:body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/Javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('#{myBean.myProperty}');
        });
    </script>        
</h:body>
```

But this doesn't evaluate the ManagedBean's property:

**index.xhtml**

```
...
<h:body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/Javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/Javascript/MyJS.js" />
</h:body>
```

**MyJS.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('#{myBean.myProperty}');
});
```

In this second case, the alert box contains the not-evaluated string `#{myBean.myProperty}`

How can I make it work from the external js file?

Comment: I think you can't from external JS, the only way as a workaround you need to pass that value to JS function from JSF page by calling it like `functionName(#{value});` and do what you want in JS file like a normal JS value

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense!

Comment: You could also convert your .js in a .jsp. There are methods in the JSF API that allow you to process EL expressions from java code.

Comment: Honestly I prefer the first suggestion because I would like to avoid using JSP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion by @Al-Mothafar, I have finally solved my issue in the following way:

**index.xhtml**

```
...
<h:body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/Javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/Javascript/MyJS.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        var myBeanProperty = '#{myBean.myProperty}';
    </script>        
</h:body>
```

**MyJS.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert(myBeanProperty);
});
```

Comment: you really better start using `<h:outputScript` http://stackoverflow.com/a/11333632/617373 and http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to change your *.js file to *.xhtml and include it with "<ui:include ... />".  To avoid the parser complaining about the use of &, < and > in your *.xhtml file, surround it with a CDATA tag.  The disadvantage of this is if the *.js file is being used in other pages, the browser won't be able to cache it.

**MyJS.xhtml (changed from MyJS.js)**

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:body>
<ui:composition>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  ...your JavaScript code here...
//]]>
</script>

</ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

In your **index.xhtml** file, do the following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  ...
<ui:include src="MyJS.xhtml" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer the following approach

```
<h:inputText id="myHiddenData" value="#{myBean.myProperty}" style="display:none">


$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("#myHiddenData").val()); // or alert($("#myFormID\\:myHiddenData").val());
});
```

I just don't like mixing js code with JSF...

Comment: You *are* mixing JavaScript code with JSF. You're just doing it inline rather than via .js files. Which is the only way it can work. JSF can't see the .js files.

Comment: @EJP I'm accessing from js a value that being passed to JSF  , I don't think that it can be called "mixing JavaScript code with JSF"

Answer (score 1):

I just was want to check something before answer, like I said in my comment :

I think you can't from external JS, the only way as a workaround you need to pass that value to JS function from JSF page by calling it like `functionName(#{value});` and do what you want in JS file like a normal JS value.

Like in your **index.xhtml**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
            functionName('#{myBean.myProperty}');
        });
</script>
```

or like :

```
<h:commandLink action="..." value="..." onclick="functionName('#{myBean.myProperty}')"/>
```

and in your js file:

```
function functionName(var1) {
// DO what you want to do with var1 or varN like normal JS value
}
```

Sure you can pass a multi-parameters not only single parameter.