# JSF outputScript and JavaScripts not parsed by EL?

Tags: java, jsf-2, java-ee-6, el

> **Possible Duplicate: The solution to this post is not feasible in this case, re-open this post please! **
>   [JSF bean property not evaluated in external JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491085/jsf-bean-property-not-evaluated-in-external-javascript-file)

The EL parser do not translate files including with the `<outputScript>` tag (JavaScript files). When trying to access the resource bundle.

`<h:outputScript library="js" name="myScripts.js" target="head"/>`;

myScripts.js file:

> alert("#{msg.browser_not_html5_compatible}");

The result is that I get the same string back when the alert window renders.

If I have this line of JavaScript in a `<script>` tag in my XHTML file, the EL parser will replace it with the correct resource string from the bundle;

```
<script>
    alert("#{msg.browser_not_html5_compatible}");
</script>
```

*Can I make the EL parser translate my included (`<h:outputScript>`) JavaScript file to access the resource bundle?*

Answer (score 1):

### Servlet

One option could be creating a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) which loads your message bundle and creates a Javascript file containing a JSON object containing the message keys and values. It might look like:

```
var messages = {
  "browser_not_html5_compatible": "You browser..."
, "other_key": "Other value"
};
```

If you have a large resource bundle and you don't want to expose all messages to Javascript you could prefix specific Javascript messages with something like `js_`. That way you can easily iterate over the resource bundle's `keySet` and only use the Javascript keys:

```
for (String key : resourceBundle.keySet()){
  if (key.startsWith("js_")){
    // Do something with resourceBundle.getString(key);
  }
}
```

On your JSF page you have to add the generated Javascript. If you need it, you can pass your view's locale to your servlet using `#{view.locale}`:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="/path-to-servlet/#{view.locale}" target="head"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="myScripts.js" target="head"/>
```

And in `myScripts.js` you can use:

```
alert(messages.browser_not_html5_compatible);
```

### JSP

A variation on the servlet option is using JSP to create the Javascript containing JSON. You can by setting the content type to `application/javascript`:

```
<%@ page contentType="application/javascript; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

You need [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) 2.2 to iterate over the resource bundle's `keySet` though (since there is no getter to access it).

Comment: Interesting solution, but don't know how this solution would hold when the application have multiple language support?

Comment: You can use `#{view.locale}` to pass the locale to your servlet as a get parameter.

Comment: I have a work-around so that the EL parser translate the JavaScript, which are in a separate file. The solution involves using the <ui:include> tag which the EL parses. But now I can not share that, since the busy people here at stackoverflow close that possibility. I can make a separate FAQ for the answer, if someone wants to see the solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "a separate FAQ for the answer"?

Comment: This post is closed, so can't post the solution here. Thanks for the effort.